# Google driver crashes when I load scroll more than 500 reviews. Is it because selenium does not support pages with too long slider?

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=air%20conditioning%20contractor%20in%20arizona&rlz=1C5GCEA_enPK991PK991&biw=1440&bih=695&sz=0&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALiCzsYq41p4v2cWzq8GwaSZ2DtO7rDvZg%3A1661178586687&ei=2pIDY6i5KfmBxc8P3cyHiAg&oq=air%20Contractor%20in%20Arizona&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i30i7k1j0i390k1l3.16624.17537.0.19019.4.4.0.0.0.0.372.713.3-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.2.712...0i30i8i7k1j0i30i7i5k1j0i30i13i5k1.0.EJJ4x3HPkzE#lrd=0x872b719aaaaaaaab:0x4c9be99024345fb0,1,,,&rlfi=hd:;si:5520262573564649392,l,CiZhaXIgY29uZGl0aW9uaW5nIGNvbnRyYWN0b3IgaW4gYXJpem9uYUiEhKSGmIKAgAhaQBAAEAEQAhgAGAEYAhgEIiZhaXIgY29uZGl0aW9uaW5nIGNvbnRyYWN0b3IgaW4gYXJpem9uYSoICAMQABABEAKSAQ9odmFjX2NvbnRyYWN0b3KqASMQASofIhthaXIgY29uZGl0aW9uaW5nIGNvbnRyYWN0b3IoAA;mv:%5B%5B33.7345389,-111.6487076%5D,%5B33.3072932,-112.43172969999999%5D%5D) is the link where you can find the Google reviews of a listing I am trying to scrape.
I have pasted the code below to get all the reviews, not more than 1200.
When my code reached to scrape more than 500 reviews, then the following error happened

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
> from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
> from tab crashed

Why is it happening? Is it because the selenium does not support lots of data handling when scrolling more than 500 reviews?

```
 all_reviews_div = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("review-dialog-list"
        )
        while True:
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", all_reviews_div)
            all_reviews = all_reviews_div.find_elements_by_class_name('gws-localreviews__google-review')
            sys.stdout.write("\r" + "Scrolling Reviews " + str(len(all_reviews))+ ' of '+ str(self.total_reviews))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            if(len(all_reviews) == self.total_reviews or len(all_reviews) >= 1200):
                break
```